# Please help me answer the stylistic transformation

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The possessive suggests a noun is needed after *captain's,* but there doesn't appear to be one in the first sentence. How do I complete the second sentence to mean the same as the first? I can't simply introduce something like *action* which isn't included in the first sentence.

> - Although the captain did everything he could to save the ship, it started to sink.
> - In spite of the captain's....

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Hopefully I've interpreted what you actually want t do here. Questions in Stack Exchange sites must be explicit.

Comment: *In spite of the captain's best efforts to do everything he could to save the ship, it started to sink.* You'll need a noun for something of the captain's, and you'll need a complement for that noun to take the place of the direct object of the original *did*.

Comment: @deadrat 'In spite of the captain's best efforts' is spot on. But can I suggest 'In spite of the captain's best efforts to save it, the ship started to sink.'

Comment: In spite of the captain's best efforts to save the ship, it started to sink. The noun 'the ship' must be the former of its pronoun' it'. That's my opinion. Please correct me if I type wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not to introduce anything new into the second sentence, then you need to form a noun out of "did everything he could". English has the *[gerund](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gerund),* a noun-like form of a verb.

> In spite of the captain's **doing** everything he could to save the ship, it started to sink.

This form is technically correct here but, because it's very literary, it is becoming increasingly uncommon. More and more, *doing* is treated as a present participle and is not preceded by a possessive.

Even without its literary nature, "In spite of the captain's doing" (or even "In spite of the captain doing") is a more complex construction than "Although the captain did" and the latter would, I suggest, be generally preferred.